# categorical feature ranking

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, cart, ranking

I would like to rank categorical features by the order or importance in a classification/regression setting.

**Input**

There are two features, which are survey questions:

1. "how is your mood?": four possible answers are crappy, mediocre, good and great!
2. "are you happy with your life?": three possible answers are no, maybe and yes.

**Output**

I am trying to predict the likelihood of a person being satisfied in a relationship, which can either be a probability on [0,1] scale (regression), or a set of 5 categories: extremely dissatisfied, dissatisfied, don't care, happy, extremely happy.

**Problem**

I am trying to rank which question is more appropriate in predicting how satisfied the person is in a relationship (if at all), and score the relevancy of the question on a categorical scale: not useful, somewhat useful, sorta useful, useful, extremely useful.

The user can answer 0, 1 or both questions (so, sometimes the user votes on their relationship happiness and I don't have any other information on the user).

**Approaches Tried So Far**

I tried the following approaches:

1. LASSO: turned the questions and answers into a binary design dummy matrix, and mapped cases with 0 questions answered to the intercept. So, in the case of no answered questions, the row of the design matrix looks like [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] (4 zeros for first question and 3 zeros for second question). I then try to infer the likelihood of a question being relevant using a scheme on the non-zero LASSO regression coefficients (which is a bit hacky) and then bin the likelihood into each of the relevancy categories.
2. Partykit::ctree. Fit a decision stump, see which question the conditional inference framework picks first, exclude the data for that question (drop feature), regress onto the next question. If at any stage the decision stump is just a node, then stop the algorithm. Relevancy is ranked by p-value.
3. Similar idea to 2, but using CHAID multiway split trees.
4. Forward/backward feature selection, rank question relevancy by the magnitude of the cross-validation error.

**Question**

Is there an algorithm or another approach which is better-suited for what I'm trying to do?